# getting error while training yolov3 :- ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I am training a custom yolov3 model and getting error "ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call." while fitting the model for training.
getting eror on fit_generator statement. Could somebody please help?

```
train_generator = BatchGenerator(
        instances           = train_ints, 
        anchors             = config['model']['anchors'],   
        labels              = labels,        
        downsample          = 32, # ratio between network input's size and network output's size, 32 for YOLOv3
        max_box_per_image   = max_box_per_image,
        batch_size          = config['train']['batch_size'],
        min_net_size        = config['model']['min_input_size'],
        max_net_size        = config['model']['max_input_size'],   
        shuffle             = True, 
        jitter              = 0.3, 
        norm                = normalize
    )


    train_model, infer_model = create_model(
        nb_class            = len(labels), 
        anchors             = config['model']['anchors'], 
        max_box_per_image   = max_box_per_image, 
        max_grid            = [config['model']['max_input_size'], config['model']['max_input_size']], 
        batch_size          = config['train']['batch_size'], 
        warmup_batches      = warmup_batches,
        ignore_thresh       = config['train']['ignore_thresh'],
        multi_gpu           = multi_gpu,
        saved_weights_name  = config['train']['saved_weights_name'],
        lr                  = config['train']['learning_rate'],
        grid_scales         = config['train']['grid_scales'],
        obj_scale           = config['train']['obj_scale'],
        noobj_scale         = config['train']['noobj_scale'],
        xywh_scale          = config['train']['xywh_scale'],
        class_scale         = config['train']['class_scale'],
    )

    ###############################
    #   Kick off the training
    ###############################
    callbacks = create_callbacks(config['train']['saved_weights_name'], config['train']['tensorboard_dir'], infer_model)
    print ("before kickoff", len(train_generator))
    print ("before kickoff", train_generator)
    **train_model.fit_generator(
        generator        = train_generator,** 
        steps_per_epoch  = len(train_generator) * config['train']['train_times'], 
        epochs           = config['train']['nb_epochs'] + config['train']['warmup_epochs'],
        #epochs           = 1, 
        verbose          = 2 if config['train']['debug'] else 1,
        callbacks        = callbacks, 
        workers          = 2,
        max_queue_size   = 8
    )
    print ("after kickoff")
```

Error am getting is :

WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layer YoloLayer has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`.
Epoch 1/21
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 300, in 
*main*(args)
File "train.py", line 269, in *main*
train_model.fit_generator(
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1815, in fit_generator
return self.fit(
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in **call**
result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 840, in _call
return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2828, in **call**
graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
File "/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

```
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/Users/karthikeyan/Desktop/table/yolo.py:46 call  *
    batch_seen = tf.Variable(0.)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:262 __call__  **
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:244 _variable_v2_call
    return previous_getter(
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
    return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
    return next_creator(**kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
    return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
    return next_creator(**kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
    return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2857 creator
    return next_creator(**kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py:67 getter
    return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
/Users/karthikeyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:701 invalid_creator_scope
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to find an answer. Including "tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)" this statement after import tensorflow resolved the issue.